# Find out changes in Magento 1.7 Core

Tags: magento-1.7, php, magento-upgrade

I am working on magento project which is been developed by some other team before several years. I need to find out whether there is any changes made by them in core files or not?

I feel it is very difficult to detect any changes done in core files manually. Please share your answers.

P.S. = I am not using any VCS

Answer (score 0):

You can download original files from github and compare them to your files using [Kompare](https://www.kde.org/applications/development/kompare/) tool if you are using linux.

Comment: Thank you. What are your opinions about Meld Diff Viewer?? I am currently trying with this. Have you used it?

Comment: I haven't used Meld , I have used Kompare for a long time and didn't feel the  need to use any other tool, also it comes bundled with many distros.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to @neo's answer. You can download the files of the Magento based on your version of Magento from [Firegento Magento Github](https://github.com/firegento/magento/tree/magento-1.7.0.2). You can select from the repository branches based on your Magento version.

So here are the steps we do to detect which core files had been changed.

- download the original version of your Magento from [github](https://github.com/firegento/magento/tree/magento-1.7.0.2)
- For the diff tools, I would prefer using [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and its [PHP Storm Diff](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/02/comparing-files-and-folders-within-your-ide/) tools.
- Create local git repository from the original Magento folder and initially commit it. This would help you track later the changes you applied from diff tools.

See the screenshot below using the diff tools from [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

[image]